# Free resources used by finished thread

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, boost-asio, libcurl

I developed a multi threaded caching proxy for **OpenWrt** (Linux for routers, so there is few RAM available). I used Boost and Curl libraries, it works fine but its RAM consumption doesn't stop increasing (Memory leak).

- I free all variables allocated dynamically
- I close all the opened files
- Clean up the initialized curl handles
- Global variable are constants

Here is a part of my main code:

```
while (true) {            
            ip::tcp::socket* socket = new ip::tcp::socket(io_service);
            acceptor.accept(*socket);
            pthread_t thread;
            pthread_create(&thread, NULL, handleRequest_thread, (void*) socket);            
            pthread_detach(thread);            
        }
```

It's sure that the memory leak occurs "handleRequest_thread", so my question is:
Is there a way to free all the resources (memory, opened files ...) after the thread is finished ?

Comment: You may have libraries that allocate thread-local memory which depending on the library implementation is not always destroyed. Try converting your program to use a thread pool to recycle threads. OpenMP will generally do this automatically. You can use the OpenMP task construct to get the same effect as `pthread_create`.

Comment: After using only one thread, my application consumes less memory but it still increasing with time :-(, I think the problem is in libcurl

Comment: using a thread per socket seems like unnecessary overhead for an embedded device with memory constraints. Why not use a single thread invoking the `io_service` and asynchronous methods?

Comment: I'm not experimented with asynchronous programming, and I have time constraints to finish the project :)

Comment: I suggest including more code in your question demonstrating the memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot free all resources automatically ( only by exiting your process, but that's not very good way ). So you have to control your recourses, use smart pointers where you can, automatically close files ( using fstream for example ) etc.
As for thread: maybe you should use boost.thread instead, it will make sure you don't forget to clean thread objects itself ( what you can easily forget using plain pthreads ).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the last part about boost thread, boost.thread cleans thread objects automatically after it finishes ?

Comment: No it does not, until you join() it, what it does is clean thread handles, when variable is out of scope. For example with pthreads you'll have to call clean functions yourself, so that's why is slightly more error prone.

Comment: So a possible solution is make another thread than the main one joins the created threads ? so the main thread can handle other requests ?

Comment: Well i don't know architecture of your app, maybe you don't need any threads at all, at least boost.asio can use async networking without using any threads, and if you use curl multi interface it can be used also in asynchronous manner.

Comment: after using only one thread, my application consumes less memory but it still increasing with time :-(, I think the problem is in libcurl

Comment: I have servers using libcurl for a long time without any memory and handle leaks, so it's not likely libcurl is to blame. First make sure you close all libcurls' handles where you have to. Best way would be to wrap all of the libraries handles in your objects, so that resource deallocation is done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Do you destroy the `ip::tcp::socket*` in the detached thread when it finishes? Memory for threads is freed on joining, but this is not neccessary for detached threads. The resources for detached thread are given back to the system when they finish. You could check the exit status of `pthread_detach` if you are able to detach the thread.

from the man pages `man pthread_create`:

> A thread may either be joinable or detached.  If a thread is  joinable,
>      then  another thread can call pthread_join(3) to wait for the thread to
>      terminate and fetch its exit status.  Only when a  terminated  joinable
>      thread  has  been joined are the last of its resources released back to
>      the system.  When a detached thread terminates, its resources are auto‐
>      matically  released back to the system: it is not possible to join with
>      the thread in order  to  obtain  its  exit  status.

Perhaps you create the threads faster then you can finish them, and hence your memory usage keeps increasing.

Comment: yes I destroy the socket at the end of 'handleRequest_thread'